# java swing two buttons communication

Tags: java, swing, button

In my swing application, I need to choose a file.and then compile that file in a terminal.But before compiling, I want to delete if other files are present in the directory of chosen file.
I have the file path but I need the parent folder path, to check other files.

```
load.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory()); 
        int r = j.showSaveDialog(null); 
        if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
            l.setText("File Ready"); 
            File selectedFile = j.getSelectedFile(); 
            path=selectedFile.getAbsolutePath(); 
        } else 
            l.setText("the user cancelled the operation"); 
    } 
}); 
compile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
        Process proc = null; 
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream())); 
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream())); 
        String s = null; 
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
        File folder = new File(path); 
       for (File f : folder.listFiles()) {
                if (f.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                    f.delete(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: the question looks very different way.I cant edit

Comment: and what is your actual question?

Comment: `path` is getting set here, but it is only a string.  If you want to *see* the path, you must set the text of a JLabel.

Comment: the first button takes a value in the path when the selection is made.but the path to the second button does not come. I defined the path at the top "public String path. @Stultuske

Comment: I don't want anything related to the label, I just want the path value to come to the second button. @Neil

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: @junior You'd simply use *path* in the action listener for the second button.  However you should also be prepared for the possibility that path is null should the second button be pressed *first*.

Comment: @Stultuske yes I debugged my code and the problem is not there.I will compile the file that the user selected later on the command line.before you compile, I want to see if there are some files in the folder where the file is located and delete them.but it doesn't work because I gave you the address of the file.I need a function that gives me path to the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is a mistake you are doing in this part

```
 File folder = new File(path); 
       for (File f : folder.listFiles()) {
                if (f.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                    f.delete();
```

The line `File folder = new File(path);` will give the file reference not folder reference So if you list other files in the path, there will be nothing.

Change it to `File folder = new File(path).getParentFile();`  You have the parent folder. Now list and delete needed files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it looks like a correct solution. I wrote path = selectedFile.getParent () into the first button; your method should be correct as well.